# Android Black Screen Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I just created an app for a way to interface with my schools online gradebook. If I set android:debuggable to "true", generate signed apk, and then put in in my samsung and run it, the app works fine, however, it is set to "false", the app does not work any more. Is this a known issue? Thanks!

Comment: It should work. debuggable set to "false" is the recommended way to publish the signed apk. Can you explain what you mean by "does not work"?

Comment: Hello, well, I really do not know what the issue was, but after running the code with debuggable set to false on a emulator, I was able to replicate the issue and found out that it had to do with a conditional in a while loop that was being skipped for some reason. I rewrote what I needed, and voila it worked. Thanks anyways.